# How to find which line has a missing attribute in a file that use a fixed pattern?

Tags: linux, bash, ldap

I have a file with a list of LDAP users with their password encoded. The file always has the same pattern as seen in the following example:

```
cn=user01,cn=users,dc=mycompany,dc=com,dc=ar
userpassword={SHA}sssFRwn116jjIF3EXEhecyFER=

cn=user02,cn=users,dc=mycompany,dc=com,dc=ar
userpassword={SHA}wwU3GCFOgidd5Z2h+jBKjsFER/w=

cn=user03,cn=users,dc=mycompany,dc=com,dc=ar
userpassword={SHA}GfGfptC2N43BDsfkqL6v0V+iFER=

cn=user04,cn=users,dc=mycompany,dc=com,dc=ar

cn=user05,cn=users,dc=mycompany,dc=com,dc=ar
userpassword={SHA}ZzZGptC2N43BFERkqL6v0V+ixUM=
```

I need some way to identify which is the user doesn't have a password (in this example the user 'cn=user04') , or at least get the line number in the file where the password is missing using linux console and/or bash scripting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like if you have awk read the file in paragraph mode you can determine whether a record is missing the `userpassword` attribute by testing if it contains a line break.

```
$ awk -F, -vRS= '!/\n/{print $1}' file
cn=user04
```

Comment: Hi ogus! Thanks a lot! Your solution was helpful

Answer (score 0):

This solution is kind of a hack, but should work in realistic cases:

```
fmt -w 999 input.txt|grep -v 'cn.*userpassword'
```

It would fail if you happen a user with the username *userpassword*, and this user has no password set; this is a case you would not recognize with this approach.